# Windows phone 8 load image from local path

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, xna

I need save path of image from Microsoft.Xna.FrameWork.Media.Picture and then in other parts of the code load this path to BitmapImage and then show this. Uri save is fine, but i can not figure out why image is not load.

```
//Gt uri of image. I try this withnout UriKind too.
//AbsoluteUri is: file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/sample_photo_00.jpg
//LocalPath is: C:\Data\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\sample_photo_00.jpg
uri = new Uri(picture.GetPath(), UriKind.Absolute);


//Create BitmapImage from Uri. 
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(photo.Url);
```

If I change the loading image to:

```
image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("someInternetAdress"));
```

It´s load ok.

thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(picture.GetPath(), UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
```

Comment: it does not work, it still behaves the same way. But thank you for your interest help me

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean it is not loading, any errors, or just nothing happening?

Comment: No error. When I show this using component Image, so there is nothig, but if I use internet URL thats work.